# How to receive values passed to ASP.NET page with HTTP GET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I'm trying to receive the values passed from other non aspx page to my asp.net page with C# via HTTP GET with Parameters. Would it be fine if I fetch the values with Request.QueryString in Page Load event?

Please advice.

Here's what I've done so far.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //fetch query from url
        string queryTimeStamp = Request.QueryString["t"];
        Int64 queryCallerID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["s"]);
        int querySMSGateway = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["d"]);
        string querySMSMessage = Request.QueryString["m"];

        //Do other processings
}
```

Comment: Request.QueryString["key"] or Request["key"] will do.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be fine? Just beware of the limitations, constraints and restrictions in a HTTP GET itself.

Comment: Then that's great! I've never done anything like this before that's why I'm taking advices. Yes. I will be aware of the limitations as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the value in `Request.QueryString` or `Request.Form` collection

Answer (score 2):

Below is the better way to go, which will handle unexpected exception, thanks:

```
string queryTimeStamp = Request.QueryString["t"];
Int64 queryCallerID;
Int64.TryParse(Request.QueryString["s"] == string.Empty ? "0" : Request.QueryString["s"], out queryCallerID);
int querySMSGateway;
Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["d"] == string.Empty ? "0" : Request.QueryString["d"], out querySMSGateway);
string querySMSMessage = Request.QueryString["m"];
```